# Importing csv file in Matlab

Tags: matlab, file-io, csv, import

I have a csv file where each column is a different test result, and each line is a different simulation. It looks something like this:

```
                (test 1) (test 2) (test 3) (test 4) (test 5)
(simulation 1)     3   ,    4   ,    6   ,   7   ,     8
(simulation 2)     9   ,    4   ,    7   ,   10  ,     7
```

Note that the text in the brackets is not in the cvs file.
I want to import this data into Matlab the same way its organized in the text file, but the resulted matrix has 3 columns and as many line as needed.

Why is that? How do I fix it?

Also, some of the numbers are imported as NaN, how do I solve it?

Thanks!

Comment: what code did you use to import?

Comment: I used the import wizard. I'm new to Matlab and still didn't go through the script tutorial

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a CSV file like:

```
3   ,    4   ,    6   ,   7   ,     8
9   ,    4   ,    7   ,   10  ,     7
```

To read the entire file, use

```
myMatrix = csvread('filename.csv');
```

myMatrix =

```
3       4       6      7        8
9       4       7      10       7
```

Answer (score 1):

If you aren't familiar with matlab basics, take a look at [`csvread`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/csvread.html).  This function imports comma separated value files and may be just what you need.  Further, examine the literature to see why you may be getting the errors you mention.  If you are still having a problem, post the code you are using to import the data and a larger example of that data, including entries that are returning NaN's.